# strong consistency for reads on aerospike - why do they need regime numbers?

Tags: distributed-system, aerospike, consistency, cap-theorem

I'm reading the [strong consistency mode for aerospike](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/consistency.html) manual. In the last example "Strong Consistency for reads", they explain that in case of a partition, they need a concept called "regime" to ensure linearization of reads. Why do we need that? writes to the minority would not succeed, as they won't be replicated, so what are we worrying about? missing writes to the active master?

Answer (score 3):

It boils down to the fact that when the cluster partitions, all nodes likely do not partition simultaneously.

Consider a single data-partition (shard) of Aerospike. The master copy from the prior regime is on the minority side of the partition without all of its replicas then it needs to give up being master while a copy in the new regime needs to promote to master. Since we are in a network partition, these two nodes cannot coordinate this exchange. The master from the prior regime may receive a read before determining it's no longer master. To ensure a linearized read, the read-transaction issues a replica ping which includes the current regime the master believes it is on. If any replica reports that the regime has advanced then the read fails, otherwise the replica-ping allows the transaction to proceed.

If any new write were able to complete on the new regime then based on the liveliness rules, it is ensured that any linearized read against the old regime will fail.

Comment: thanks! but I re-read and I think I want to correct you: the client read-transaction shouldn't issue a replica ping at all. I think it just needs to remember the latest regime it encountered in this session. as long as it reads from the old master, and never sees the new regime, there's no problem. once one of its queries sees the new regime, it remembers it and if a subsequent query is routed to the old regime - NOW it will reject it as it already saw data from the new regime.

Comment: You are describing 'Sequential' aka Session consistency, you question was about 'Linearizable' consistency. For 'Sequential Consistency', you would be correct and that is how we have implemented it. Linearized reads deal with all processes and threads in the system, not an individual session.